# JVM Crash and Disk/kernel Read-error - Is there a correlation?

Tags: java, jvm

We are finding that our JVM crashes quite inexplicably after a minor version update of the JRE. Intially this was the suspect. But after correlating the time of crash with syslog messages I found that everytime there is a crash there was this memory error from the kernel logged. There is enough RAM; but I guess swap is still used by linux. The assumption is that the disk error has caused the JVM to crash. Is this a fair assumption?

JVM Crash stack

```
be-7.2.1/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer /home/cicd/sonarqube-7.2.1/temp/sq-process3072857830430806886properties
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx60g
2020.02.06 11:51:16 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ce] is up
2020.02.06 11:51:16 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is up
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f7df7918531, pid=13479, tid=0x00007f6e59cf9700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_242-b08) (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.242-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0xa42531]  Symbol::increment_refcount()+0x1
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/xxx/sonarqube-7.2.1/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid13479.log

[error occurred during error reporting , id 0x7]

# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
2020.02.18 07:35:17 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 134
2020.02.18 07:35:17 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2020.02.18 07:35:21 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [ce] is stopped
2020.02.18 07:35:24 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2020.02.18 07:35:24 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

Error in syslog

```
"kernel: blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector"
  [libjvm.so+0xa42531]  Symbol::increment_refcount()+0x1

Feb 18 07:35:14 xxx kernel: Read-error on swap-device (253:1:2227784)
Feb 18 07:35:14 xxx kernel: Read-error on swap-device (253:1:2227792)
Feb 18 07:35:14 xxx kernel: Read-error on swap-device (253:1:2227
```

The disk is an older IBM HW, and from other servers had failed before

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               IBM
Product:              ServeRAID M5110
Revision:             3.45
Compliance:           SPC-3
User Capacity:        5,996,996,984,832 bytes [5.99 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Logical Unit id:      0x600605b0072bb48022f34180127fc92d
Serial number:        002dc97f128041f32280b42b07b00506
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Wed Feb 19 06:44:22 2020 EET
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability
```

Comment: In a word, yes. The paging error causes the bus error.

Comment: Have you enabled crash dumps and looked at the backtrace?  Is there enough swap space to handle all the RAM needed?  Are there any kernel updates that address this? What kernel are you using?  Search the net for "blk_update_request" and "read-error on swap-device". I found this, not sure if that's your issue: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=linux-4.16.y&id=7859056bc73dea2c3714b00c83b253d4c22bf7b6

Comment: BTW: Your question is possibly better searched for and asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com. @user207421 is saying that it's reading in pages from the swap-file and that's the direct cause of the SIGBUS, but you should really be get a crash dump and looking at the stack trace. You can then start to try to see the the flow through the kernel code by looking at the kernel source for the kernel version you're using. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source

Comment: Yes, this a fair assumption. Generally, when the kernel log says there’s a critical hardware error, you should solve that before worrying about particular software problems…

Comment: @Holger, oh...it wasn't 100% clear to me that it was a hardware error reported by the OS except anecdotally through the poster's question. Worth replacing the disk if feasible. Not sure if the lack of SMART capability of the disk indicates an older disk or if that's just because it is in a RAID array.

Comment: @clearlight I consider “Read-error on swap-device” an alarming sign. I doesn’t need to imply a permanent defect, e.g. data transfer could be affected by heating problems, there are a lot of possibilities. But the result is disastrous in either case. I was a bit surprised about the lack of SMART either…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user207421 has mentioned it is due to the Read error that JVM crashed. ( the libjvm.so in the log nails it)

Had this read error a few more times in this machine. But those times there was no 
 JVM crash and there was no log of libjvm.so in syslogs too

```
Mar  4 03:49:33 xxx kernel: blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 15250816
Mar  4 03:49:33 xxx kernel: XFS (dm-2): metadata I/O error: block 0x425d80 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 61 numblks 32
Mar  4 03:49:33 xxx kernel: XFS (dm-2): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error -61.
Mar  4 03:49:37 xx kernel: megaraid_sas 0000:1b:00.0: 17102 (636601577s/0x0002/FATAL) - Unrecoverable
```